# Jwt authentication problem - invalid credentials

Tags: php, api, authentication, laravel-5, jwt

When i used the auth on created user in Laravel, it's works, but... when I changed to my database, I could no longer validate it.

The user's password is encrypted with bcrypt, when doing a **Hash::check()**, the return is **true**, but **JWT validation is always returning me false.**

I have a problem using the following code:

```
$credentials = $request->only('email', 'senha');
try {
   if(! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)){
     return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 400);
   }
}catch(JWTException $e){
   return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
}

return response()->json([
  'access_token'  => $token,
  'token_type'    => 'bearer',
  'expires_in'    => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60
]);
```

I checked some articles like [this](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/184) from the resource page itself and some others just couldn't find the solution!

The laravel version is 5.2!

EDIT

The fields in Database are called 'email' and 'senha' (pt-br language). When i changed fields, the errors is same!

Comment: you might want to try to pass the password field to attempt as the name 'password', even if it isn't named that, that is usually how the user providers know which field is supposed to be hash checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating a new table in the bank using Laravel standards.

Answer (score 0):

`JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)` part will look for the input values 'email' and 'passowrd'.

So in credentials you have to pass `$request->only('email', 'password');` not `$request->only('email', 'senha');`

Comment: The fields in Database are called 'email' and 'senha' (pt-br language). When i changed fields, the errors is same!